# Automatically submit multiple forms one after the other

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, redirect, form-submit

I am working on a registration form that once paid for the selected services the user will be directed to a page that will add the user `id` automatically to all the events he has selected, while doing so in the back, I am showing a dynamic loader to the user before redirecting him to the invoice page.

Now I have look online and probably should use AJAX, but really struggling to figure this one out.

Here is the function I have that is, it is dynamic and depends on the number of services that the user selected (It can be as much as 80 different forms...). The function is triggered by `window.onload`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submitform()
{
  // Look if select program is a program
  yachtClubModifier.submit();
// if no results we do nothing


 registerAthlete1.submit();

  createInvoice.submit();
}

</script>
```

It all works out, but the page get's redirected before all the forms are submitted... I am new to all of this and pretty sure their's a better way of doing it.

Comment: When a form submits, it's default behavior is to send POST or GET data to your `<form id='form1' action='here.php'>` *(to the action)*. To bypass the default behavior: `document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = e=>{ /* AJAX to Server and back here */ e.preventDefault(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
 function submitForm(e){
      e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            url: "example.php",
            data: $("#form1_id").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (dataofconfirm) {
                // do something with the result
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "example.php",
            data: $("#form2_id").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (dataofconfirm) {
                // do something with the result
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "example.php",
            data: $("#form3_id").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (dataofconfirm) {
                // do something with the result
            }
        });
    }
```